# composer.phar file could not be downloaded

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

i am trying to install composer, i have already downloaded the installer, the instalation stopped showing this error :

> The "https://getcomposer.org/download/1.8.5/composer.phar" file could
>   not be downloaded: failed to open stream.

if i choose the wamp/php/5.6 then the installation will be completed,but if i choose wamp/php/7.3 then the installtion wil be failed

Comment: Can you access that phar file from your browser? (Just to check firewall issues)

Comment: how can i do it ?

Comment: Just open another tab in the browser you are using right now and go to https://getcomposer.org/download/1.8.5/composer.phar instead of https://stackoverflow.com :-)

Comment: when i clicked this link composer.phar has been downloaded

Comment: Maybe your firewall is allowing your browser to pass but not the installer, and you need to give her privileges to access the net?

Comment: thank you, how can i give privileges to composer installer ?

Comment: That's up to your Operative System... google it "manage firewall in windows", "manage firewall in Fedora" ...